# Getting DPI-1043: invalid number while trying to insert row

Tags: python, oracle

I'm trying to insert a row into Oracle and I'm getting this error. I can't find why this is happening (the error doesn't give which column is causing the problem).

This is the dictionary i'm trying to insert:

> {'mac': 'string', 'network_time_id': 20210623, 'kbps_in': 32.0,
> 'kbps_out': 15.0, 'snr_ds': 28.1, 'snr_us': 31.0, 'pwr_ds': 0.7,
> 'pwr_us': 41.7, 'pwr_us_cmts': 7.0, 'ploss': 0.0, 'delay_cm': None,
> 'jitter': 75.96, 'dsFecPre': 0.11315852162015343, 'dsFecPost':
> 0.0010413241703495324, 'usFecPre': 0.04774052478134111, 'usFecPost': 0.0014577259475218659, 'leases': 0, 'mtr': 16.6, 'dsTilt': 8.4, 'dsTiltAbs': 8.4}

This is the insert statement:

```
sqlStaging = ('INSERT INTO st_modem_client_status_mongo(MAC,  NETWORK_TIME_ID,   KBPS_IN,  KBPS_OUT,  SNR_DS,  SNR_US,  PWR_DS,  PWR_US,  PWR_US_CMTS,  PLOSS,  DELAY_CM,  JITTER,  DSFECPRE,  DSFECPOST,  USFECPRE,  USFECPOST,  LEASES,  MTR,DSTILT,DSTILTABS)' 
            'values(:mac,:network_time_id,:kbps_in,:kbps_out,:snr_ds,:snr_us,:pwr_ds,:pwr_us,:pwr_us_cmts,:ploss,:delay_cm,:jitter,:dsFecPre,:dsFecPost,:usFecPre,:usFecPost,:leases,:mtr,:dsTilt,:dsTiltAbs)')
```

And this is the table:

[image]

Does anyone know what could be happening? Is it "None"?

Answer (score 0):

I created a table (would be better if you posted `CREATE TABLE`):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test(
  2    delay_cm         NUMBER(38,2),
  3    dsfecpost        NUMBER(38,20),
  4    dsfecpre         NUMBER(38,20),
  5    dstilt           NUMBER(38,2),
  6    dstiltabs        NUMBER(38,2),
  7    jitter           NUMBER(38,2),
  8    kbps_in          NUMBER(38,2),
  9    kbps_out         NUMBER(38,2),
 10    leases           NUMBER(38,0),
 11    mac              VARCHAR2(12 CHAR),
 12    mtr              NUMBER(10,2),
 13    network_time_id  NUMBER(38,0),
 14    ploss            NUMBER(38,1),
 15    pwr_ds           NUMBER(38,2),
 16    pwr_us           NUMBER(38,2),
 17    pwr_us_cmts      NUMBER(38,2),
 18    snr_ds           NUMBER(38,2),
 19    snr_us           NUMBER(38,2),
 20    st_modem         NUMBER(38,0),
 21    usfecpost        NUMBER(38,20),
 22    usfecpre         NUMBER(38,20)
 23  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Successfully inserted values you posted:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO test(
  2    mac,
  3    network_time_id,
  4    kbps_in,
  5    kbps_out,
  6    snr_ds,
  7    snr_us,
  8    pwr_ds,
  9    pwr_us,
 10    pwr_us_cmts,
 11    ploss,
 12    delay_cm,
 13    jitter,
 14    dsfecpre,
 15    dsfecpost,
 16    usfecpre,
 17    usfecpost,
 18    leases,
 19    mtr,
 20    dstilt,
 21    dstiltabs
 22  )VALUES(
 23    'string',
 24    20210623,
 25    32.0,
 26    15.0,
 27    28.1,
 28    31.0,
 29    0.7,
 30    41.7,
 31    7.0,
 32    0.0,
 33    NULL, -- none,
 34    75.96,
 35    0.11315852162015343,
 36    0.0010413241703495324,
 37    0.04774052478134111,
 38    0.0014577259475218659,
 39    0,
 40    16.6,
 41    8.4,
 42    8.4
 43  );

1 row created.

SQL>
```

You asked whether `none` is a culprit; as you can see, I used `null` instead, which is - in Oracle - absence of a value. However, with `none`, error is not the one you got:

```
SQL>  insert into test (delay_cm) values (none);
 insert into test (delay_cm) values (none)
                                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

However, if you enclose it into single quotes, then yes - it is the `invalid_number` because column is declared as `number` and you're trying to put a string into it (which can't be implicitly converted to a valid numeric value):

```
SQL>  insert into test (delay_cm) values ('none');
 insert into test (delay_cm) values ('none')
                                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number


SQL>
```